# Проблема с сессиями в PHP: падает сервер

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте, уважаемые! Возникла неприятная проблема с БД, либо с самой сессией.
Дело в том, что пишу модуль, который проверяет авторизован ли человек, и в случае если нет - вывод формы логина.

Код вот, пояснения под ним:

```
<?php 
unset($_SESSION['logged_user']);
session_start();
require_once('db.php');
$sql_connection = dbConnect();

function LoginForm(){

    if(!empty($_POST['user'])){


        $sql_get_info = "SELECT `name`, `password`, `group` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '".$_POST['user']."' ";
        $data = mysql_query($sql_get_info, $sql_connection) or die;

        if($data['password'] == $_POST['password']){
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $_POST['login'];

            switch($date['group'])
            {
                case 10:
                    {
                    $_SESSION['group'] = 10;
                    break;
                    }
                case 20:
                    {
                    $_SESSION['group'] = 20;
                    break;
                    }
                default: {echo "Ваши права неопределены. ";}
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "Неверный пароль".
            LoginForm();
        }
    }

    echo "
    Авторизуйтесь для продолжения. <br>
    <form method = 'POST'> 
        <input type = 'text' name = 'user'><br>
        <input type = 'password' name = 'password'><br>
        <input type = 'submit'><br>
    </form>";
    die();
    }


if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])){

LoginForm();


}
?>

Успешная авторизация.
```

*Копия на gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ddda3ff6893f3dd944e*

Дело в том, что при таком раскладе после вызова функции 4-5 строка с подключением БД "забываются", и из-за этого null передавался в один из параметров в строке 13, из-за этого была ошибка:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given
>   in C:\Winginx\home\manager.loc\public_html\protect.php on line 13

Насколько я понял, в тело функции надо было внести require_once файла с функцией подключения к БД+объявить начало сессии, чтобы она видела их:

```
unset($_SESSION['logged_user']);
session_start();
require_once('db.php');
$sql_connection = dbConnect();
```

Я это сделал, т.е.:

```
function LoginForm(){

       unset($_SESSION['logged_user']);
       session_start();
       require_once('db.php');
       $sql_connection = dbConnect();


    if(!empty($_POST['user'])){...
```

В итоге, после ввода данных и их отправки - сервер начало...**ложить**. Попросту страница падала с ошибкой Time-out, и более того - потом вовсе не запускалась даже другая страница на сервере, то есть пришлось перезагружать.
В логах ошибки и сервера, и PHP ничего нету.

Использую winginx.

Похоже, тут дело в сессии и так далее.

По поводу БД:
С require_once'той функцией подключения к БД всё хорошо, я её и на других страницах сервиса использую, а тут такие проблемы...

---

Нынешний код, с которым сервер падает:

```
<?php 
unset($_SESSION['logged_user']);
session_start();


function LoginForm(){

session_start();
require_once('db.php');
$sql_connection = dbConnect();

    if(!empty($_POST['user'])){


        $sql_get_info = "SELECT `name`, `password`, `group` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '".$_POST['user']."' ";
        $data = mysql_query($sql_get_info, $sql_connection) or die; 

        if($data['password'] == $_POST['password']){
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $_POST['login'];

            switch($date['group'])
            {
                case 10:
                    {
                    $_SESSION['group'] = 10;
                    break;
                    }
                case 20:
                    {
                    $_SESSION['group'] = 20;
                    break;
                    }
                default: {echo "Ваши права неопределены. ";}
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "Неверный пароль".
            LoginForm();
        }
    }

    echo "
    Авторизуйтесь для продолжения. <br>
    <form method = 'POST'> 
        <input type = 'text' name = 'user'><br>
        <input type = 'password' name = 'password'><br>
        <input type = 'submit'><br>
    </form>";
    die();
    }


if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])){

LoginForm();


}
?>

Успешная авторизация.
```

*Копия на gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e3bf63abb5fdd06068c8*

Comment: `mysql_*` устаревшее расширение. Впишите в начало скрипта `error_reporting(E_ALL)` и `ini_set('display_errors', true)` и перезапустите скрипт. Для проверки сессии сделайте `var_dump($_SESSION)` после `session_start()`. Можно ещё што нибудь перед этим туда записать для наглядности.

Comment: @Naumov, 
Выбило:
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\Winginx\home\manager.loc\public_html\protect.php on line 10

Т.е. оно не даёт сессии сработать из-за объявления сессии в функции? Сейчас попробую без этого...
UPD: Закомментировал session_start(); в функции - в итоге notice пропало, но сервер всё-равно ложит(504 Gateway Time-out)

Comment: Смотрите логи сервера, скорее всего из за `mysql` покажите вывод `phpinfo();`

Comment: Ради теста записал в сессию число 1 и всё нормально вывело. То есть, дело в самой функции LoginForm...

Comment: ну, во первых `session_start()` указывается в самом начале файле, до него лучше чтобы вообще ничего не было, все удаляй что выше есть, во вторых, `session_start()` может быть только одна. Из под функции её точно надо убрать. И зачем ты unset делаешь, у тебя никогда не пройдет авторизация пользователя, она сразу будет сбрасываться, а код выполняться по новой

Comment: @Naumov, вряд ли, дело в том, что я сервис небольшой пишу, и эту функцию использовал неоднократно - всё было чудесно! Но не в этот раз... Вот с phpinfo данные по mysql: http://i.imgur.com/Ht5UnaB.png

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, убрал session_start() с функции - также ложит сервер. Поставил session_start() в начало также - не дало эффект, ложит сервер...По поводу unset - я читал, что так можно избежать дописывание нужного параметра через адресную строку, т.е. если человек ?logen_in=admin дописал. Убрал его - также нету никакого эффекта, сервер ложит.

Comment: Ты с сессией работаешь, и что что человек get параметр допишет к адресу, ты с ним не работаешь, ты работаешь с сессией и формой.

Comment: Закоментируй вызов `LoginForm()` после `echo 'неверный пароль'` просто скрипт в рекурсию уходит.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, хорошо, спасибо за совет, теперь буду внимательнее с этой функцией. Вот только проблема основная не решена :(

Comment: И после `isset($_SESSION)` тоже надо закоментировать `LoginForm()`

Comment: @Naumov, и в правду - проблема была в повторном вызове после echo! Вот я дурак, столько с этой проблемой намаялся. Спасибо Вам добрый человек!!!

Answer (score 2):

Накидал небольшой пример:

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Your code is here ^_^

if ($_POST) {

    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Авторизоваться') {
        // тут должна быть твоя проверка авторизации
        $_SESSION['isLogin'] = true;
    }

    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Выйти') {
        unset($_SESSION['isLogin']);
    }
}

if ($_SESSION && $_SESSION['isLogin']) {
    echo 'Я авторизованный';
    echo '
        <form method="post">
            <input name="action" type="submit" value="Выйти" />
        </form>
    ';
} else {

    echo '
        <form method="post">
            <input name="action" type="submit" value="Авторизоваться" />
        </form>
    ';
}
```